# What to say to your boss if they want you to use a global variable

Tags: teamwork, coding-standards, singleton

I am currently 4 months into an internship, and when reviewing my code, my boss didn't like that I had kept a specific object local to a number of methods across a few separate classes within one assembly.  He didn't like that I was created a new object each time, and instead told me to create a single object that can be accessed from anywhere.  I have therefore had to create it as a static object within a static class, and simply reference it from here I want to use it!

How would you deal with this, as I have only been programming professionally for 4 months!

Comment: Is your boss a technical person or non-technical person? If he's technical, has he read "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin?

Comment: So, your boss hired you to code, and is now telling you how to code?

Comment: You said in a comment below that "the object doesn't have any state, apart from a lot of constants".  In that case, a static class seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: @Justin: Why a "class" at all (assuming of course you work in a language that didn't caught the insane idea that everything must be in a class)?

Comment: "Yes Boss" springs to mind...

Comment: "told me to create a single object that can be accessed from anywhere. I have therefore had to create it as a static object " This isn't valid reasoning. You speak as if having a single object accessible from an entire application implied you had a Singleton -- why don't you just create it in the aggregation root and then pass its reference to the dependent classes?

Comment: thank him for pointing out what you're doing wrong, jeez, why are you being so stand-offish when you are clearly inexperienced, read up on singleton pattern, etc, you shouldn't create a new object each time if a singleton or static class will do, that takes up extra memory. Maybe it just seems weird to you because you're not used to it but I think you will come to like static classes once you start using them and see their benefit in certain situations, creating new objects is only for when the state is mutable, otherwise you do not need a new instance of the class

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If one object is enough, creating an object every time is a waste, and *here* your boss may be right.

The problem is proper access to that object. A factory-like method with proper visibility which always returns that static object is the first solution that springs to mind. Others certainly exist.

Comment: +1: as much as i dislike any "GoF said so" answer, right is right.

Comment: I did think about Singletons, however I just saw it as a wrapper around a global variable, so I didn't follow it up.  I will give this a try now, as the object doesn't have any state, apart from a lot of constants so should be fine.  Thanks.

Comment: I suspected this might be the case ("object doesn't have any state... a lot of constants").  Your boss is right.  There's no sense in putting artificial pressure on the garbage collector for values that never change.

Comment: @darren-young: on a side note, having no state is interesting and allows for some powerful approaches; take a look at so called 'functional programming' if you didn't yet.

Answer (score 8):

I can't  comment your specific case, but using global variables *is* sometimes a good solution. Java's [System](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class is full of static, global variables.

But in general, if you think you're right and your boss is wrong, then why don't you ask your boss to explain *why* he thinks a global variable is a better solution? A plain "I don't like it" is as vague as "global variables are evil". You must demand more from your boss!

If he can't give reasons for his stance, and you can give reasons to your stance, or vice versa, then it's a good learning opportunity. If both of you can justify your stances, then it's probably a matter of taste - or matter of experience: your boss must have been programming professionally more than 4 months, I think?

Comment: See, `java.lang.System` contains exactly three global variables, and for each of them there's a method to properly set it. But `System` is full of static methods which return global objects, and there's exactly nothing wrong with this, can't argue.

Comment: Yes; I consider global variables pretty much same as static methods that return global objects.

Comment: So Java does this. It’s a different question *entirely* of whether that’s a good idea. C’s standard random number generator keeps global state. But it’s generally acknowledged that this is *horrible*, and that the random number generator is therefore unusable in certain applications (see e.g. Bentley et al., *Engineering a sort function*). Java in particular has a host of design problems (that have been partly improved upon in C#) so I’t be *very* wary of using it as an argument like this.

Comment: @Konrald Rudolph: In the end it's a design decision. Every decision has pros and cons. For example, keeping global state in `System` simplifies, say, 99.9 % of use cases at the cost of causing problems in the remaining 0.1 %. There's no "right" answer to whether or not that 0.1 % is worth the extra complexity.

Answer (score 5):

As someone in your position, the most you can do is learn.  If the object is essentially a constant (i.e. it can't change and it doesn't maintain state), then your boss may be right.  There is no harm in having a static constant object.  After all, how many definitions of PI are there?

Some people defend the "no global objects" mindset to the point of religious ferver.  That's for one of two reasons: they've been bit by difficult to track bugs or system fragility due to overuse of global variables/objects, or they've heard that it's bad and they can't think for themselves.  I personally fall into the group of people that have been hit hard by fragility and hard to track bugs--but I've also learned some balance here.

If I were in your shoes, I'd go ahead and do what the boss says--it's his butt on the line after all.  Then I'd watch and see the effects of that choice over time.  This is an effective learning tool.

Comment: It's an internship.  You're supposed to be learning.  Blindly doing what your boss says isn't learning.

Comment: Nor is blindly going against your boss. My advice, as it was written, was to observe the effects of the boss' choice. We (on stackexchange) can't make a value judgement on the situation because we are missing vital information. This is a case to do a little scientific method. The OP has a hypothesis, boss has challenged it. Now it's time to perform the experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specific situation, a global variable might be the best solution. In embedded programming, globals are not occupying stack space and for that reason a good choice.

Globals or not, I have found it a good praxis to put a prefix on globals. This will make other programmers googling your code aware of the impact if the mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what your boss wanted was you to use the Singleton Pattern. Its a very good practice when you need to access a certain object from multiple instances.

Here is a link to the [wikipedias explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I think the `good practice` would be to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection